# React State Updating after code requiring state change runs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a grid of Nodes, which update when clicking/dragging on them. I'm running into a weird React State where the state is updating after the code following it runs.

Expected behaviour:

- nodeTypePointer is set to 0 as default react state
- Click on Blank Node, nodeTypePointer is set to 0 (unchanged) + logic uses 0
- Click on Coloured Node, nodeTypePointer is set to 1 + logic uses 1

Actual behaviour

- nodeTypePointer is set to 0 as default react state
- Click on Blank Node, nodeTypePointer remains unchanged + logic uses 0
- Click on Coloured Node *for the first time*, nodeTypePointer is set to 0 (unchanged) + logic uses 0, then *after code is finished* nodeTypePointer is set to 1
- Click on Coloured Node *for the second time*, nodeTypePointer is now still set to 1, logic uses 1, then *after code is finished* nodeTypePointer is set to 0

[image: This can be seen on this screenshot]

I know that the state is async but unsure about the exact reason/problem/solution to go on. Unsure about how to pass parameters to the next functions if I were to use a UseEffect.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Node from './Node'

import './Grid.css';

const rectDiameter = 25
const gridHeightRatio = 0.9

const Grid: React.FC = () => {

    const gridHeight: number = Math.floor(window.innerHeight * gridHeightRatio)
    const gridWidth: number = window.innerWidth

    const numX: number = Math.floor(gridHeight / rectDiameter)
    const numY: number = Math.floor(gridWidth / rectDiameter)

    const tempGrid: number[][] = [...Array(numX)].map(() => Array(numY).fill(0));

    const [grid, setGrid] = useState(tempGrid)
    const [isMousePressed, setMousePressed] = useState(false)
    const [nodeTypePointer, setNodeTypePointer] = useState(0)

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Use Effect', nodeTypePointer)
    }, [nodeTypePointer])

    // Hacky el.ID to workaround React performance until I know how to do it better
    const paintNode = (x: number, y: number) => {
        const el = document.getElementById(`${x}-${y}`)
        if (!el) return
        if (nodeTypePointer === 0) {
            el.classList.add("node-wall")
        } else {
            el.classList.remove("node-wall")
        }
    }

    const updateGridPosition = (x: number, y: number) => {
        const newValue = nodeTypePointer === 0 ? 1 : 0
        let newGrid: number[][] = grid
        newGrid[x][y] = newValue
        setGrid(newGrid)
    }

    const handleMouseDown = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>, x: number, y: number) => {
        console.log('Node pointer type Before', nodeTypePointer)
        setNodeTypePointer(grid[x][y])
        console.log('Node pointer type After', nodeTypePointer)
        setMousePressed(true)
        console.log('Before updated Grid', grid[x][y])
        updateGridPosition(x, y)
        console.log('After updated Grid', grid[x][y])
        paintNode(x, y)                             // <------------- Uses nodeTypePointer
    }

    const handleMouseUp = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>, x: number, y: number) => {}

    const handleHover = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>, x: number, y: number) => {
        if (!isMousePressed) return
        updateGridPosition(x, y)
        paintNode(x, y)
}

    return (
        <div className='gridContainer' >
            {
                grid.map((row: number[], i: number) =>
                    row.map((val: number, j: number) =>
                        <Node
                            x={i}
                            y={j}
                            d={rectDiameter}
                            key={`${i}-${j}`}
                            state={val}
                            onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
                            onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
                            onHover={handleHover} />
                    )
                )
            }
        </div>
    );
}

export default Grid
```

Any help on understanding the problem and suggested solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State changes are asynchronous (both component ones and hook ones). So your state hasn't update by the time you call `paintNode`. There's 2 ways I can think of around it. One is to put the call to `paintNode` in your `nodeTypePointer`'s `useEffect`, like so:

```
 useEffect(() => {
     paintNode(x,y);
 }, [nodeTypePointer])
```

but this means you'll need to store the `x` and `y` of clicked one in some standard variables, since you won't be able to pass them directly to `useEffect`. Another way (and maybe a better one, since I'm not a huge fan of state changes having side effects) is to just pass the x/y directly into `paintNode` during the `handleMouseDown` function:

```
paintNode(x, y, grid[x][y])
```

however it looks like `updateGridPosition` also needs the x/y, so maybe you *would* be better off storing the raw clicked one in state, then having a `useEffect` for the clicked one that does everything needed once a node is clicked. All depends on how this function is gonna end up looking.

But yeah, the reason for your bug is cause state changes are async so it hasn't updated by the time you call `paintNode`

Comment: Thank you! I've added the extra code in onHover and onUpdate Grid if that helps.

I'll give your suggestions a try tomorrow morning, thanks!

Comment: Having just spent some time on it, this useEffect would work for the onMouseDown, but I'd have to dup the code the hover as it's similar but without the trigger